# How do I concat string with the content which is a binding property in button which is inside DataTemplate in UWP?

Tags: uwp-xaml

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SectionsTemplate">
        <Grid Background="LightSkyBlue">
              <Button Content="{Binding ItemsCount}"></Button> 
        </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

I want to add "Items" string with {Binding ItemsCount} in content of button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a Converter for this:

**Add a new convertor into your project**

```
public class PrependStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return (string)parameter + " " + (string)value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        // implement for two-way convertion
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }        
}
```

**Add reference to Converter in Resources**

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:PrependStringConverter x:Key="PrependStringConverter" />
</Page.Resources>
```

**Use converter in data binding**

```
    <Button Content="{Binding ItemsCount,  ConverterParameter=Items, Converter={StaticResource PrependStringConverter}}">
    </Button>
```

---

And there is another option: to split the content of your button in two parts with some grouping element like StackPanel:

```
    <Button >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="Items&#160;"/>
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemsCount}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
```